# Is there a video player that allows to reproduce one audio track through left channel and the other through right one?

Tags: audio, playback, video-player

I hope this is the right place...

I normally use [MPC-BE](https://www.videohelp.com/software/MPC-BE) and [MPC-HC](https://www.videohelp.com/software/Media-Player-Classic-Home-Cinema) (which has quite audio processing options including a *custom channel mapping*, although it doesn't seem to go that far with tracks), but I've also tried many others and never found such level of control over audio tracks and channels. What I'd want is e. g. reproduce a dual video file and can choose send English language audio track to the left channel and the Spanish one to the right, so I can hear both at the same time and in perfect sync.

I don't think so, sincerely... but if one don't ask